# Using autofill with a MAX function within a macro

Tags: vba, excel, max, autofill

I know you've answered similar topics which I have tried to duplicate, but I am a novice and apparently need the answer spelled out for me! I am trying to apply autofill code to a MAX formula column within a Macro, so that it will autofill to different row counts each time.

```
Range("AC2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-2],RC[-1])"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AC2:AC285")
Range("AC2:AC285").Select
```

Thank you!

Comment: The code above works. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to change it so the macro will apply autofill to that MAX column to the correct number of rows, since I will have a different row count each time I run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only important to fill the formula down to the last value within the columns referenced within the formula.

```
dim lr as long
with worksheets("sheet1")
    lr = application.max(.cells(.rows.count, "AA").end(xlup).row, _
                         .cells(.rows.count, "AB").end(xlup).row)
    .Range("AC2:AC" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-2],RC[-1])"
end with
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no blanks between the first and last row in column AC this will work and you don't even need `AutoFill`

```
With Range(Range("AC2"),Range("AC2").End(xlDown))
     .FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-2],RC[-1])"
End With
```

This works specifically becuase you are using R1C1 notation which can be applied across all cells.

If there may be blanks, you can find last row like below and fill the formulas the same way:

```
Dim lastRow as Long
lastRow = Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("AC2:AC" & lastRow)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-2],RC[-1])"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have two main tasks:

- how to define last row in a given column;
- how to define range, based on a row and column;

This is the answer both:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim currLastRow As Long
    currLastRow = lastRow(columnToCheck:=4)

    With Worksheets(1)
       .Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-2],RC[-1])"
       .Range("D1").AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(1, "D"), .Cells(currLastRow, "D"))
    End With

End Sub

Function lastRow(Optional wsName As String, Optional columnToCheck As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    If wsName = vbNullString Then
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Set ws = Worksheets(wsName)
    End If

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnToCheck).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

The `lastRow` function gives the last row per column. In your case, you want column `D`, e.g. the 4. column.